# Passing dictionary values in python as command line inputs to c++ code

Tags: python, c++

I have a wrapper file that is reading a JSON file into a dictionary. 
I am using the `os.system("command")` command to run a C++ code in this python file. 
The C++ code takes command line inputs which are key values in the parsed dictionary.

How can i pass a **python variable** as a command line input for a **C++** code using the `os.system("command")` instruction?

Comment: could you please show what you have tried so far/any relevant code

Comment: You could format the keys and values like e.g. `"--key1=value1 --key2=value2 ..."` etc. Then append that to the string containing the command. The actual format of the string depends on what the command you want to call can handle of course.

Comment: Is this about how to pass command line arguments from Python, or is it about how to do the C++ side to receive that information exactly? The only system independent solution to the latter is to use an ASCII encoding such as base 64, and explicitly decode in the C++ program.

Comment: Hey, I figured!..I just had to typecast the value to string and append..as @JoachimPileborg mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that unless you relax one of the restrictions.

Relax the python dict requirement:  The command line has a well defined text arguments interface, which can easily handle all the info.  You can pass the json filename, the str representation of the dict, or pass name-value pairs as command line arguments.

Relax the system call requirement: Rather than building an executable from the c++ code, you can build a python c++ extension.  The c++ code can export functions that take a python dict.

Relax the c++ requirement: Obviously you could code it in python.